# Curl HTTP Post VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, curl

please help i am getting an error message when i tried to convert a curl post request into vb.net

Curl
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzY1MDY3MzIsImlzcyI6IlpFRURMQUJTIiwicm9sZU5hbWUiOiJtZXJjaGFudCIsImRlYWxlciI6ImJvZGxpbmsiLCJleHAiOjE2MDgwNDIuiidjYTRRTMXMSUwNjczMiwidXNlcklkIjoiSXNhYWN3b3JsZDJyZXZvIn0.NC0x7kxg2-1X6vpPlYCsAFbST1QnZMxk_R9FYta2304" 'https://api.topupbox.com/services/api/v2/w1/balance'

Request URL
https://api.topupbox.com/services/api/v2/w1/balance

Request Headers
{
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "authorization": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzY1MDY3MzIsImlzcyI6IlpFRURMQUJTIiwicm9sZU5hbWUiOiJtZXJjaGFudCIsImRlYWxlciI6ImJvZGxpbmsiLCJleHAiOjE2MDgwNDIuiidjYTRRTMXMSUwNjczMiwidXNlcklkIjoiSXNhYWN3b3JsZDJyZXZvIn0.NC0x7kxg2-1X6vpPlYCsAFbST1QnZMxk_R9FYta2304"
}

This was what was giving to me from the api documentation, works well in a browser but cannot get it to work in VB.NET.

Comment: Can you please describe what you already tried and also what you want to achieve since its very broad like this.

Comment: Try check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769645/webclient-equivalent-of-curl-command

Comment: sir, i have  checked the link, i still dont get it sir. pls can u help with a sample code please

Comment: Bro the idea is that you try to learn you ask us to give you code that is working.